# Convert key=value blocks to CSV

Tags: shell, text-processing, csv

I am trying to transpose a content of a file into another.

Input file `Test.txt`:

```
HLRSN = 3
IMSI = 404212109727229
KIVALUE = A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CA9
K4SNO = 1
CARDTYPE = SIM
ALG = COMP128_3

HLRSN = 3
IMSI = 404212109727230
KIVALUE = A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CB8
K4SNO = 1
CARDTYPE = SIM
ALG = COMP128_3

HLRSN = 3
IMSI = 404212109727231
KIVALUE = A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CD6
K4SNO = 1
CARDTYPE = SIM
ALG = COMP128_3
```

Output needed in another text file:

```
3,404212109727229,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CA9,1,SIM,COMP128_3
3,404212109727230,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CB8,1,SIM,COMP128_3
3,404212109727231,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CD6,1,SIM,COMP128_3
```

Comment: Are the fields `HLRSN`, `IMSI`, `KIVALUE`, etc. always present in each input block and in the same order each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `bash` solution:

```
declare -a out

EOF=false
IFS=$'='

until $EOF; do
  read -r skip val || EOF=true
  if [ ! -z "$val" ]
  then
    out+=("${val//[[:space:]]/}")
  else
    tmp="${out[@]}"
    printf '%s\n' "${tmp// /,}"
    out=()
  fi
done < file
```

**How does this work**

- Declare array `out` for holding output line, set variable `EOF` to keep track end of file, `IFS` for input field separator for `read`.
- Until we read end of file, we read each line of file, set value of last field to variable `val`.
- `if [ ! -z "$val" ]`: check if length of variable `$val` is not zero, we remove space in `$val`, push it to array `out`.
- if length `$val` is zero, meaning we get blank line or end of file, we assign all element of array `out` to variable tmp, then replace all space variable `tmp` by `,`, our designed output recode separator.
- Set `out` to null for next work.

Another solution, more concise, shorter for you is using `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'=' -anle '
    BEGIN { $, = "," }
    push @out,$F[-1] if @F;
    print @{[map {s/\s// && $_} @out]} and @out = ()
        if /^$/ or eof;
' file
3,404212109727229,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CA9,1,SIM,COMP128_3
3,404212109727230,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CB8,1,SIM,COMP128_3
3,404212109727231,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CD6,1,SIM,COMP128_3
```

Comment: You can avoid the `EOF` variable by using `while read -r skip val || [ ! -z "$skip" ]`

Comment: Is `skip` a variable or a modifier to the `read` command ?

Comment: @user1598390: It a variable.

Answer (score 11):

Simply:

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '{print $3,$6,$9,$12,$15,$18}'
```

An empty *record separator* (`RS=`) enables the *paragraph mode* whereby records are separated by sequences of empty lines. Inside a record, the default field separator applies (records are separated by blanks) so in each record, the fields we are interested in are the 3rd, 6th, 9th...

We change the *output* field separator to a comma character (`OFS=,`) and print the fields we're interested in.

Comment: Great solution! If it happens to be variable number of lines, you can make it more general with `awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=3) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":OFS)}' file` - that is, to print every 3 fields.

Comment: I love how the line `awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '{print $3,$6,$9,$12,$15,$18}'` is prefixed with the adverb "simply".

Answer (score 3):

Save the following to a file (eg `split.awk`)

```
BEGIN {
RS="\n\n";
FS="\n";
ORS=",";
}

{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    {
        split($i, sf, "= ")
        print sf[2]
    }
    printf "\n"
 }
```

Then run:

```
awk -f split.awk Test.txt
```

Or run the whole command as one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n";FS="\n";ORS=",";}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i, sf, "= ")print sf[2]}printf "\n"}' Test.txt
```

---

It works as follows:

- The `BEGIN` block runs once at the start and sets the record seperator (`RS`) to two newlines and the field seperator (`FS`) to a single newline. The output record seperator (`ORS`) is set to a comma.
- It then loops through each field in the record (`NF` is the number of fields in the current record) and splits it on "= ".
- It then prints the right hand of this split with a comma between each (the `ORS`)
- After each line it prints a newline to give you the CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers... I needed a slight modification, because I was in need of the column header in the final CSV-file. This is my awk-solution:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '
    NR==1 {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,line,"= "); 
        printf "%s%s", line[1], (i==NF ? "\n" : ",");
      }
    } 
    {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,line,"= "); 
        printf "%s%s", line[2], (i==NF ? "\n" : ",");
      } 
    }'
```

As in the other answers, this reads the entire block (until a blank line) in fields, then splits each field again with split(). The only difference is that for the first record, it prints the part before the '=' and in a second for-loop, it prints the right-hand-side for all records.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) we may read the data as records delimited by double linefeeds containing fields delimited by single linefeeds, containing key-value pairs delimited by equal signs. We may remove extra whitespace and empty columns (the result of reading the data with these delimiters introduces a space at the start of each field's value), and then convert it to CSV:

```bash
$ mlr --ips = --ifs lf --irs lflf --ocsv clean-whitespace then remove-empty-columns Test.txt
HLRSN,IMSI,KIVALUE,K4SNO,CARDTYPE,ALG
3,404212109727229,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CA9,1,SIM,COMP128_3
3,404212109727230,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CB8,1,SIM,COMP128_3
3,404212109727231,A24AD11812232B47688ADBF15CE05CD6,1,SIM,COMP128_3
```

Would you not want the CSV header in the output, use `mlr` with its `-N` option. Miller will automatically quote any field that contains embedded delimiters or quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If all the blocks have exactly the same format (same field names, in the same order), then you can use awk in “paragraph mode”, and print the desired field number in each block. If there are always spaces around the equal signs and the values never contain spaces, you can rely on whitespace-separated fields.

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS=',' '{print $3, $6, $9, $12, $15, $18}'
```

If you can rely on the order and presence of fields but not on the whitespace, then you'll need a bit of parsing to split at the equal signs.

```
awk -v RS= -F '\n' '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        sub(/[^=]*= */, "", $i);
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n" : ",");
    }
  }'
```

Here's a Perl method:

```
perl -000 -ne '
    $, = ","; $\ = "\n";
    @kv = split /\n| *= */;
    print @kv[grep {$_%2} 0..$#kv];
  '
```

If the fields in the blocks can come out of order and you always want a specific order as output, you'll need to store the fields and print them out in the right order at the end of each paragraph. In awk, this is easier to do in line mode than in paragraph mode.

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    match($0, / *= */) {a[substr($0,1,RSTART-1)] = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}
    /^$/ {print a["HLRSN"], a["IMSI"], a["KIVALUE"], a["K4SNO"], a["CARDTYPE"], a["ALG"]; split("", a)}
    END {print a["HLRSN"], a["IMSI"], a["KIVALUE"], a["K4SNO"], a["CARDTYPE"], a["ALG"]}
'
```

This one is a one-liner in Perl.

```
perl -000 -F'/\n|\s*=\s*/' -ane '%F = @F; $\ = "\n"; $, = ","; print @F{qw(HLRSN IMSI KIVALUE K4SNO CARDTYPE ALG)}'
```